# Made some great course slides, now what?

Tags: teaching, mooc, presentation

I just spent a year preparing a set of course slides for an introductory course in engineering, and they now look really good.  In addition to posting them on my web page, what more can I do to get use out of them?

For example, it would be nice to see if there's a MOOC that would be interested in them, but it doesn't seem like any of the major ones ever solicit such things.

I'm not aware of any examples of "publishing" slides either, so I'd be curious what more experienced users here have done.

Comment: How do you know those slides contain correct contents?

Comment: Taught the course with them, made corrections as I went along.

Comment: This is what many of us do every day of the week. Use them to teach your students well.

Comment: *what more can I do to get use out of them?* Use them to teach. Publish them as free content on your personal website or your university website sub-domain; or sell them electronically. What more are you expecting from educational slides?

Comment: If you can, release them on an open license (e.g. [CC BY](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/)) - it will allow others to benefit from it (and cite/refer to your original slides). Of course, if you are allowed to by your univ.

Comment: Seconding Piotr Migdal's suggestion, I'd recommend being very explicit about what sort of adaptation is allowed, preferably through an appropriate Creative Commons license.  The key question is whether people can modify the slides or extract content from them.  If not, then the slides are useful only for inspiration or to people who plan to give more or less the same lecture as you did.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some ideas:

Make a video of yourself presenting the slides (either to a class, or just to the camera), and upload it to YouTube (or similar). Others have done this, and as a result there are some great free resources available for people who otherwise would not have the time or money to take the course. For example, [N J Wildberger](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXl0Zbk8_rvjyLwAR-Xh9pQ) has several maths courses online. If you don't want to be on the video, you can just have the slides, with your voice presenting them. (See the videos of [Bill Shillito](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFsZ2CadKpAt_yInoTcVRnQ), for example.)

Put the materials on your website, and spread the news.

Turn the materials into a [wikibook](https://www.wikibooks.org/), where others can add to them.

Put the materials on [OER Commons](https://www.oercommons.org/), [Curriki](http://www.curriki.org/), [MyOER](http://www.myoer.org/), or [Share My Lesson](http://www.sharemylesson.com/). I haven't used any of these myself (yet), so I don't know which would be most appropriate for university-level or postgraduate teaching materials.

Answer (score 1):

Your university may have a digital institutional repository where you can post the slides together with related course materials.